How I can solve error "Sorry! Your are not allowed to upload this type of file!" in listing pro theme on Wordpress?
I'm using Listing Pro Theme to make a directory website and Whenever I try to upload a file in Claim Now form on any business page, this error comes:
"Sorry! Your are not allowed to upload this type of file!"
I'm not able to find the solution so far.
I tried to search on their Youtube Channel and other resources on internet but end up getting nothing related to that.

What type of file do you try to upload?
